# How to use StreamProvider dependent on value from another StreamProvider

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a flutter (flutter + firebase) app which has two StreamProviders like this:

```
  return MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      StreamProvider(
        initialData: null,
        create: (context) => _userService.getUserStream(),
      ),
      StreamProvider(
        initialData: null,
        create: (context) => _userService.getPartnerStream(),
      ),
    ]
  );
```

I have been using the first StreamProvider to get the authorized user which corresponds to a User in firestore and then stream that firestore document and return an AppUser instance. I'm then using that state like this: `AppUser appUser = Provider.of<AppUser>(context);`.

How do I get the second SteamProvider to wait until the first one has returned an AppUser so I can use that for the second StreamProvider?

Comment: You can use `futures` and `await`  for this. Please check the [following documentation](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) if it helps you.